# Turn off screen programmatically android

Tags: android

I am trying to build an app that would launch a service that will turn off the screen when a criteria is met, but it wouldn't lock the phone.

I don't want to use PowerManager class because the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) says *"Device battery life will be significantly affected by the use of this API."* and the main objective of the app is save battery.

Is there any other way to turn off the screen (not just set the brightness to minimum) and keep the phone running all the applications?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps !

Minimize the screen timeout time.

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 100);
```

Comment: requires this permission:-                       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off screen by overriding system screen turn off time.

First get system turn off time

```
int defaultTurnOffTime = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 60000);
```

then put your turn off time `Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 1000);`

and when the screen turned off, `set default turn off time` `Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, defaultTurnOffTime);`

add below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```