# android programmatically screen off above Nougat

Tags: android, screen

search and find method, like
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417227/turn-off-screen-programmatically-android)

but it doesn't work above Nougat, hope someone give me idea about programmatically turning off screen no matter device rooted or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my rep is not enough to comment your post. But i got a question, did you grant [permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) to write setting yet ? Because from Android M, you have to ask user to grant [permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting), if not it will not work

Comment: sure, I have added some permissions into manifest, like below
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />, but no luck for me, still not work.

Comment: No, you have to to use runtime permission, please check this link: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: yes, I know that these permissions should be requested at runtime, and I have already done these, but still no working for me above Nougat